# Verifying Predefined Java Rules on a Set of Java Source Files

Tags: java, coding-style

I am looking for a tool which verifies that a set of java source files (not the byte code) follows a set of predefined rules.

**For example**, if we have a predefined rule which says any method contains an assertion, the method name must have the suffix "*xxxTest*". In order to keep the code clean, all the developers must follow these rules/conventions. Of course code reviewing would solve this problem however there should be a way to automate these simple code style checking.

In addition, the developer should be able to run this tool locally on his change-set before committing.

To solve this problem, I started to write my own verifier using the [javaparser](https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser) which will be executed using a gradle task. However in order to avoid re-inventing the wheel, I was wondering if there are existing tools which allows me to do this or even close (may be I can contribute to it)!

**UPDATE:**

I am aware of CheckStyle and Sonar for static analysis. However I need to run this tool on the CI (ex, Jenkins) as part of the build. So the build should fail if the convention is not applied.

Comment: why down voting and 3 votes to close the question ?

Comment: This is ridiculous really when people think they are too smart to help

Comment: After doing some research, I found an answer to my question. However, I cannot post it since the question is on hold.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit where you added your answer to the question because questions should not contain answers. I understand that you can't post an answer but you should instead focus on editing your question to bring it on topic instead of editing in a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can test [JArchitect](http://www.jarchitect.com) and its powerful query language [CQLinq](http://www.jarchitect.com/cqlinq).
For your specific need you can execute the folowing query

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can easily build this tool combined [JavaParser](https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser) and [java-symbol-solver](https://github.com/ftomassetti/java-symbol-solver). The first one produces an AST of your source code and with the second one you can solve symbols (for example finding all the ancestors of a given class).

If your rules are simple enough you could probably get away just using JavaParser. That would be nice because JavaParser has very few dependencies and it is very mature and established.

Answer (score 0):

Use a tool like [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/).

It either allows you to configure a rule-set for your styleguide or you can write an extension.
There is also extensive support to integrate it into IDEs and build process.

Comment: I am aware of CheckStyle. However I forgot to mention that I need to run this tool on the CI (ex, Jenkins). So the build should fail if the convention is not applied.

Comment: @TeFa Checkstyle has good support for CL, Ant and Maven. E.g. for ant there is a `failOnViolation` attribute which allows you to stop the build if the convention is violated.

Comment: thanks I wasn't aware of this. However, is it possible to define a rule in CheckStyle like "All classes within package X shouldn't have any usages of classes within package Y". This rule is used to ensure that multilayered software architecture is not violated.